# Can anyone recommend a light-weight Asset Management Tool for a Small Organization (25 assets)?

Tags: asset-management

I have been using [zendesk](http://zendesk.com) as a light-weight web-based help desk application for my organization (15 employees; 25 machines), and I am quite happy with it, however they don't currently have any asset management.

I am looking for the following features:
- web-based application
- simple
- only needs to track 25 - 50 assets (machines)
- inexpensive

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For something that small, why not a spreadsheet on Google Docs?  It's web-based, can be shared, has access controls, revision history, color coding, etc.  I use that for IP address management on smaller network subnets and it does a fine job.  Just keep a current printout handy somewhere in case they have an outage or your Internet goes down for a while and you need immediate access to look something up.

Comment: +1, I was about to recommend Excel

Answer (score 14):

Check out Spiceworks. Its free, easy to use, and light-weight. It has a help desk system and asset management. The community around it is very helpful and there are a ton of 3rd party add-ons that extend its capabilities. After installing it and letting it scan your network, you will be surprised at the information it returns.

http://spiceworks.com/

Comment: btw I am not affiliated with spiceworks in any way. ; )

Comment: SpiceWorks seems like the perfect solution here.  Free and build just for this.  You will get cool additional features as well.  Highly recommended.

Comment: +1 for Spiceworks, have been using it for Years and I love it.

Answer (score 1):

We have a solution for Asset Management in the works - we will announce something soon :-)

Cheers,
Michael, Zendesk

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Lansweeper](http://www.lansweeper.com/) for about 6 months now.  It's extremely easy to deploy, it scans easily and seems to be pretty stable.  They have a free version (which I use) that is very feature-rich, but the paid version might offer some additional features that you would find useful.  The license for the paid version is a one-time fee of $200.

Answer (score 0):

OCS Inventory NG

Comment: Bob: if you provide your experience (good/bad etc.) and if it's easy to use/setup - I will vote you up. -james