# What is a good cost effective IT asset management solution?

Tags: asset-management

Looking for something that looks nice, is flexible with reporting, and can track everything you would expect with good IT asset management.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/10055/can-anyone-recommend-a-light-weight-asset-management-tool-for-a-small-organizatio

Answer (score 2):

I have had a lot of success with [GLPI](http://www.glpi-project.org/spip.php?lang=en). It's a nice looking, easy to use web-based asset management system.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/

Automated with agents to monitor computers (hardware and installed software). Agents available for Win/Mac/Linux.

I've used this solution myself, and I'm very happy with it.

Comment: I've used it too, for a network composed of 160+ Windows workstations. I've generated my own HTML report by querying the database.

Comment: "Looks nice" might be a stretch, but this is a powerful free tool and it is not hard to write a little bit of SQL code and run customized queries against the OCS Inventory database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen

www.lansweeper.com/
www.i-doit.de/
Jose - Dokumentation (germany)
www.faq-o-matic.net/2008/11/10/jose-21-schon-wieder-ein-kleines-update/
SYDI   sydiproject.com or httxxxp://ogenstad.net/

Also mabye "Winventory" may be a good option

Answer (score 0):

You could try NetSupport DNA

http://www.netsupportdna.com/

Tracks all hardware and software, and will notify you of changes.  It also includes an application stopper and internet filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Spiceworks](http://spiceworks.com/) for a few years now and I absolutely love it.  Doesn't require an agent, as it uses WMI, so only a firewall rule and Admin privileges on the box.

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing lansweeper at my work and we're extremely happy with the product.  Some of the nicest features: free version, custom reports, custom fields to track assets or other important info, easy to install.  Currently our test is up to 300 computers and servers.  It's working great.  Highly recommend it to others.