# Monitoring a Mac-centric network

Tags: monitoring, mac-osx-server

Our network has several sites, each with a Mac server (most of which are running Leopard Server), Airport Extremes, Cisco switches, printers, lots of Mac clients, and then a back-end server room with things such as a firewall, a VOIP system, mail server, web server, etc.

I really would like to be monitoring our system.  As I haven't a lot of time to dedicate to the task, I'd like to be able to do it incrementally (ie. monitor servers at a couple of locations, and then airports at a couple of locations, and then servers at a few more locations, and so on, as I have time to set it up.)  It is worth noting that some of the devices (notably the Airport Extremes) get their addresses via DHCP.

I've tried a few of the monitoring systems.  Some don't compile cleanly on the Mac.  Others, once you get them installed, have things built-in to monitor Linux and Windows servers, but nothing for Mac servers (and, one assumes, nothing for Airports).

[Yes, I know that Server Admin provides some monitoring features, but I dare say it is limited.]

Can anyone recommend some software for monitoring a Mac-centric environment?  Are there any guides for, after you've deployed a typical system, what you need to do to make it monitor a Mac environment?  Am I out to lunch thinking that I can build things up as I have time, or do I need to spend an entire week learning about monitoring and creating custom profiles or even hacking on software to get something to work?  If there is a for-pay solution, what did you think of it, and how can I convince management to spring for it?

Thanks!

---

Other Relevant Questions:

- [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)
- [What tool do you use to monitor your clients?](https://serverfault.com/questions/22663/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-clients)
- [How does one deploy server monitoring software on the Mac?](https://serverfault.com/questions/28417/how-does-one-deploy-server-monitoring-software-on-the-mac)

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm the Zenoss Community Manager

Zenoss will monitor your mix of devices, services and servers no problem.  It can monitor everything you've described and there is an installer available for OS X and we have a lot of OS X users (including most of our developers and QA).  Plus it's free and open source and there's a very large and active community of users.  I personally monitor several Leopard and Snow Leopard boxes and Airport Extremes and Expresses, so I know those work just great.  There's lots of documentation and training available on http://zenoss.org.

Comment: I actually just installed Zenoss (and was impressed with the installer).  It didn't find a thing when I scanned the network (and I thought I had the right SNMP settings for the Airports, and had the right SSH settings for our client Macs).  I wanted to add a server manually, but it didn't seem that /Servers/Linux was quite right, I couldn't find the /Devices/.../Darwin.  In short, I wasn't able to start with it really quickly.  I have poked around the site.  Is there a handy guide for using it for Mac admins?  [I need more time to look into it, I know; I just haven't got much to spare.]

Answer (score 2):

We've been using a combination of Nagios (google this, since I can't post more than one link due to reputation issues, I guess) and [Lithium](http://www.lithiumcorp.com).    Lithium's got a new version coming out next week and it looks really promising.   After it arrives, we'll consider again getting rid of our Nagios implmenetation (which has been running on a G5 XServe for many years now).

Lithium's a lot easier to get up and running and the new version has a lot of flexibility for configuring new devices.    There's also a companion iPhone app for Lithium starting with the latest version.

Nagios is free and open source and can be difficult to configure, but has a lot of users out there.

Answer (score 0):

[Intermapper](https://www.fortra.com/product-lines/intermapper) works well on Macs.  It's a bit network centric (switchports and uplinks) rather than service centric, so getting it to monitor e-mail servers and web servers can be more cumbersome.  That being said, it's pretty simple to configure and get working.